# creating text file and saving in unix format in java

Tags: java, unix

I need to write java code to be able to work in Unix environment for file operations. As I need to deal with files, how do I create and save a file in Unix format in Java?

Comment: This link can give you a brief Idea:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Unix format" is simply a text file that denotes [line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) with `\n` instead of `\n\r` (Windows) or `\r` (Mac before OSX).

Here's the basic idea; write each line, followed by an explicit `\n` (rather than [`.newLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--) which is platform-dependent):

```
public static void writeText(String[] text){
  Path file = Paths.get("/tmp/filename");
  try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    for(String s : text){
      bw.write(s);
      bw.write("\n");
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to write to "+file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `\n` or `\r\n`, use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Comment: Thanks dimo414 and Eng.Fouad. The above example helped a lot.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Generally speaking, true, but if you want a Unix-format file no matter what OS you're on, you'll want to use `\n` explicitly.  Getting the system's line separator means you'll get different behavior depending on the OS you run the program on.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has good documentation on that:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html