# Selecting EOL with java.nio.files

Tags: java, nio, java.nio.file

How can I select Unix end of line `\n` using `java.nio.file.Files.write` ?
Is it possible?
I do not find any option or constant to be selected.
Here is my method

```
import java.io.File;
//...
public void saveToFile(String absolutePath) {
        File file = new File(path); 
        try {
            Files.write(file.toPath(), lines/*List<String>*/, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: whats the problem you are facing whats the content of `lines`?

Comment: I need to save lines into file and it works but there are DOS(\r\n) eols in the file and I don't know how to select UNIX ones(\n) instead.

Comment: you want to save file in unix format?

Comment: does it help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530796/creating-text-file-and-saving-in-unix-format-in-java

Comment: I hope so, but I have to make me sure about UTF_8 encoding, thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot accept two answers unfortunately; frustrating when both provide useful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have another choice but to open a `BufferedWriter` to the file and write by hand:

```
try (
    final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file.toPath(),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
) {
    for (final String line: lines) {
        writer.write(line);
        writer.write('\n');
    }
    // Not compulsory, but...
    writer.flush();
}
```

(or you do as @SubOptimal says; your choice!)

Comment: Thanks, it works :) I tried to omit bufferedwriter(to be honest, don't know why )

Comment: Note that if you use Java 8 you could use a foreach on a stream out of your list of lines

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite the `line.separator` property

```
System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");
```

**PRO**: you could use `Files.write(...` with UNIX lineends also on non-UNIX environments
**CON**: changing this property most probably will have unexpected side effects

Or you write the lines inside a loop.